# Is it possible to accelerate using multiple threads directly over the algorithm interface provided by PCL

Tags: c++, windows, openmp, point-cloud-library, 3d-reconstruction

I'm new to multithreaded parallel processing. I was recently working on a 3d reconstruction of a box. I used FPCS algorithm for point cloud coarse registration, but the program needed a relatively long time to run.  In the header file of the FPCS algorithm, a function is described as follows.
[image]

OpenMP is mentioned in the function description above. So, I try to use multithreading for program acceleration.
But how can I do that?
Do I have to compile PCL source code and then make changes to it?

The following is the original call to the FPCS algorithm. Can I directly modify this program to achieve the purpose of parallel acceleration?
[image]

Any suggestions will be apprecaited!

Answer (score 0):

I think that I know the solution to the problem. In the source code of FPCS algorithm, there is some code look like this:

```
#ifdef _OPENMP
do something here
#endif
```

So I added `#define _OPENMP` to my program. And it works,but the acceleration is not obvious.